# How to save a .fits file after editing it without losing the header?

Tags: python, header, fits

I have a .fits file that I am editing and whilst I can edit and plot it fine when I save it I lose all the information in the header. This is my code below:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = fits.getdata('myimage.fits')

ID = 403

newim = np.copy(myim)

newim[newim == ID] = 0
newim[newim == 0 ] = -99
newim[newim > -99] = 0
newim[newim == -99] = 1
```

All the above is fine but its when I got to save the new fits file I get issues. Ive tried the following but again **it does not save the information included in the header:**

```
hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(newim)
hdu.writeto('new image.fits')
```

Is there any way to save my image without losing all the information in the header?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conserve header when saving an edited .fits file with Astropy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59091888/how-to-conserve-header-when-saving-an-edited-fits-file-with-astropy)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [your previous question of almost the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59091888/how-to-conserve-header-when-saving-an-edited-fits-file-with-astropy)?  Did you try my answer?

Answer (score -1):

I managed get an answer from a friend:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = fits.getdata('myimage.fits')
403header = fits.getheader('myimage.fits')

ID = 403

newim = np.copy(myim)

newim[newim == ID] = 0
newim[newim == 0 ] = -99
newim[newim > -99] = 0
newim[newim == -99] = 1

hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(newim, header=403header)
hdu.writeto('new_image.fits')
```

Comment: This does work but it's not a very effective way to work with the library.  Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59113662/982257) to your previous question on this.